# SQL Server query plan cache and plan reuse for stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of about 3 million rows in a SQL Server 2012 database. The ETL package inserts about 50,000 new rows to the table.

Right after the insert, the ETL package updates the newly added rows using a stored procedure. The procedure has an input parameter for the `ExecutionID` to filter only the rows which were inserted. I have created the indexes based on the query and if the statistics for the table are up to date then the query performance is great. However, the stats are not updated every day since the number of added records don't force auto update stats to fire.

My understanding of stored procedure plans was that the optimizer caches the plan and then reuses it until the plan gets invalid. Because of that I was expecting that if I run the procedure with plan I want once, the plan should get reused. However, I see multiple plans in the plan cache for the same procedure.

Why would that happen? In other words, why would SQL Server cache different plans for the same query?

Should I in this case update the stats manually before calling the procedure? It seems that the optimizer uses the parameter value to determine the plan and since the stats were not updated for the new batch of data, it won't use the proper plan.

Comment: What does your procedure code look like? If you build up a separate query for each `ExecutionID`, then there's nothing to cache and reuse. Also: the plan will stay in cache *until SQL Server chooses to discard it*, so if your system is tight on memory, it could be discarded rather quickly....

Comment: not sure about what you mean by build up a separate query. The proc builds a CTE for all historical data filtering only data relevant to the latest ExecutionID passed through the parameter and then updates the table again based on the ExecutionID, CTE and other conditions. What I have noticed after monitoring it is that once the "bad" plan is cached then it reuses it until the stats are updated. So if I query the cached plans right now I see 2 plans for the same proc. the good one which is not used and the "bad" one that is reused. If I update the stats and rerun the proc the good one is used.

Comment: However, since the next day we have a new ExecutionID, the bad plan is  again used probably because the optimizer checks the stats and decides the plan (good) is not the best plan to use and based on the info at hand it uses the other one. Does this mean parameter sniffing and reuse of cached plans are dependent on other things like stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ExecutionID` is auto-incrementing then what is most likely happening is that new values are not featuring in the various histograms and stats (because it's new).  As a result, the optimiser knows nothing about the cardinality of that number and makes a poor guess.

I'd suggest you want to

1. Import data
2. Rebuild stats
3. Do the update

or you can freeze a plan

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/02/19/plan-guides-plan-freezing-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx

Alternatively you can put an index hint on the update so that it uses the correct plan no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your suggested methods will work. As mentioned I was trying to understand why the cached plan was not used and a new plan was generated by the optimizer leading to the issue. Based on the comments I think the cached plans are not always used depending on things like stats. In other words, parameter sniffing and reusing cached plans are dependent on other criteria.